# Show that $|y_{n+1} - x_{n+1}| \le \frac{|b-a|}{4^n}$ for $x_{n+1} ={1\over 2}(x_n + y_n)$ and $y_{n+1} = \sqrt{{1\over 2}(x_n^2 + y_n^2)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, inequality, recurrence-relations

This question is the last part of the problem statement which was not included in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2998653/verify-proofs-related-to-monotonicity-of-x-n1-1-over-2x-ny-n-and-y).

> Let:
>   $$
> \begin{cases}
> x_{n+1} = {1\over 2}(x_n+y_n)\\
> y_{n+1} = \sqrt{{1\over 2}(x_n^2 + y_n^2)} \\
> x_1 = a > 0\\
> y_1 = b > 0 \\
> n\in \mathbb N
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   Prove that:
>   $$
> |y_{n+1} - x_{n+1}| \le \frac{|b-a|}{4^n}
> $$

I think the author is expecting the properties from the linked question to be utilized, but i don't see how.

I've started with the following:
$$
y_{n+1} - x_{n+1} = \sqrt{{1\over 2}(x_n^2 + y_n^2)} -{1 \over 2} (x_n + y_n) = \\
= \frac{{1\over 2}(x_n^2 + y_n^2) -{1 \over 4} (x_n + y_n)^2}{\sqrt{{1\over 2}(x_n^2 + y_n^2)} +{1 \over 2} (x_n + y_n)} = \frac{{1 \over 4}(x_n - y_n)^2}{\sqrt{{1\over 2}(x_n^2 + y_n^2)} +{1 \over 2} (x_n + y_n)} = \\
= \frac{(x_n - y_n)^2}{4\sqrt{{1\over 2}(x_n^2 + y_n^2)}+2(x_n + y_n)}
$$

But i do not see how to proceed from here. I guess I should somehow use that:

$$
\begin{cases}
y_n > x_n \\
x_{n+1} > x_n \\
y_{n+1} < y_n
\end{cases}
$$

Or is it even a wrong starting point? How do i prove what's in the problem statement?

Comment: idk, maybe you can also prove a lower bound on $x_n+y_n$ by induction on $n$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple calculation shows that
$$
 \sqrt{{\frac 12}(x^2 + y^2)} \ge \frac 12 (x+y) 
$$
for all non-negative real numbers $x, y$ (compare [Root-Mean Square-Arithmetic Mean-Geometric Mean-Harmonic mean Inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Root-Mean_Square-Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean-Harmonic_mean_Inequality)).

Then, continuing with your computation,
$$
| y_{n+1} - x_{n+1}| = \frac{\frac 14 (x_n - y_n)^2}{\sqrt{{\frac 12}(x_n^2 + y_n^2)} + \frac 12 (x_n+y_n)}
\le \frac{\frac 14 (x_n - y_n)^2}{x_n + y_n} \\
= \frac{|y_n - x_n|}{4} \cdot \frac{|y_n - x_n|}{x_n + y_n} \le  \frac{|y_n - x_n|}{4}
$$
and the result follows with induction.

Comment: Thank you very much, i've been able to follow with induction from your answer.